# Проверка формы на английские буквы

Tags: javascript

Проблема в том, что если написать в форме и русские и английские, то будет все норм. Как сделать так, чтобы если хотя бы один символ будет из англ, то возвратит ложь

```
function validate() {
    var z = document.forms["test"]["text"].value;
    if (z != null && z != "") {
        if (/[^a-z][а-я]/.test(z)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            document.getElementById('ros').setAttribute("class", "par")
            document.getElementById('ros').innerHTML = '';
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно просто:

```
if (/[a-zA-Z]/.test(z)) {
    // тут есть англ буквы
}
else {
    // тут нет англ букв
}
```